# If $M$ is a finitely generated free $R$-module, then $Hom_R(M,R)$ is a free right $R$-module of the same rank

Tags: solution-verification, modules, free-modules

This is part of exercise 11 b) of the book "Abstract Algebra" by Dummit and Foote.

> Let $R$ and $S$ be rings with 1 and let $M$ and $N$ be left $R$-modules. Assume also that $N$ is an $(R,S)$-bimodule. 
> (a) For $s \in S$ and for $\varphi \in \operatorname{Hom}_R(M, N)$ define $(\varphi s): M \rightarrow N$ by $(\varphi s)(m)=\varphi(m) s$. Prove that $\varphi s$ is a homomorphism of left $R$-modules, and that this action of $S$ on $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, N)$ makes it into a right $S$-module. Deduce that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, R)$ is a right $R$-module, for any $R$-module $M-$ called the dual module to $M$. 
> (b) Let $N = R$ be considered as an $(R, R)$-bimodule as usual. Under the action defined
> in part (a) show that the map $r \mapsto \varphi_r$ is an isomorphism of right R-modules:
> $Hom_R(R, R)\cong R$, where $\varphi_r$ is the homomorphism that maps $l_R$ to $r$. Deduce that
> if $M$ is a finitely generated free left R-module. then $Hom_R(M, R)$ is a free right
> $R$-module of the same rank. (cf. also Exercise 13.)

My idea was to use that $Hom_R(R,R) \cong R$ as right $R$-modules, and that, since $M \cong R^n$ for some $n$,
\begin{equation}
Hom_R(M,R) \cong Hom_R(R^n,R) \cong (Hom_R(R,R))^n \cong R^n \cong M,
\end{equation}

which would prove the claim. Is this reasoning correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct.

If $M$ is a finitely generated *free* $R$-module, then, for some $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$, we have $$M \cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{n} R$$ so that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M,R) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(\bigoplus_{i = 1}^{n} R,R) = \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{n}\operatorname{Hom}(R,R) \cong \bigoplus_{i = 1}^{n} R$$ where I use the fact that if $M_\alpha$ is an $R$-module for all $\alpha \in A$, and $N$ is an $R$-module, then $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} M_{\alpha},N) = \prod_{\alpha \in A}\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M_{\alpha},N).$$ In the case when $A$ is finite,, this reduces to $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(\bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} M_{\alpha},N) = \bigoplus_{\alpha \in A} \operatorname{Hom}_{R}(M_{\alpha},N)$$ as well as the fact that $$\operatorname{Hom}_{R}(R,R) \cong R$$ as you show in b).

Edit: I should add that you have to argue that it is a free *right* R-module. That is free is what you have shown. But this (I think) follows easily from what you show earlier (in the problem you reference).